# WPF: Change color by touching in listbox

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I want to change the background color of an item of the list when it touched. Can I do this in XAML?

```
        <ListBox x:Name="lstFlags">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                         ...
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: You could add an onClick event, and change the color in the viewmodel?

Comment: In which tag add onClick?

Comment: whichever tag you want to have the hit target for. Probably the grid?

Comment: **The property 'onClick' was not found in type 'Grid'**

Comment: Ah yes, mousedown and mouseup.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `MouseDown` or `MouseUp` event to `Grid`, but that wouldn't tell you which item was selected. What you need is to catch the selection-changed event and change the color of the selected item.

Also instead of just changing the color on selection, it's best to put a flag in your data items telling you whether they have been touched or not, then update the color in XAML based on the value of that flag.

Say we have this view model:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string ItemText { get; set; }

        private bool _wasTouched;
        public bool WasTouched
        {
            get { return _wasTouched; }
            set { _wasTouched = value; OnPropertyChanged( "WasTouched" ); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged( string name )
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if( handler != null ) handler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( name ) );
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        Items.Add( new Item() { ItemText = "ugh." } );
        Items.Add( new Item() { ItemText = "whee" } );
        Items.Add( new Item() { ItemText = "nee" } );
        Items.Add( new Item() { ItemText = "ping" } );
        Items.Add( new Item() { ItemText = "neeeuuwwwop" } );

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged( object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Item).WasTouched = true;
    }
}
```

There's an `Item` class that has some text and a boolean variable indicating whether it's been touched or not. The class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that when you change the value of `WasTouched` it can notify the XAML. We create a few items and add them to a collection that will be visible to our XAML. Also we have a `ListBox_SelectionChanged` event which gets the selected item and marks it as having been touched.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemText}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WasTouched}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

In the XAML, we tell the `ListBox` about the items and the selection-changed handler. We tell it to display each item using a `TextBox` with the item's text.  Then we modify the style you've already provided... we set the item's background to green normally, but we add a `DataTrigger` on `WasTouched` that changes the background to red.

There's one more problem: The list draws the selected item with a blue background which overrides your background color. That's what the `Style.Resources` section is for - it tells the XAML to draw selected items with a red background.

Comment: The property 'SelectionChanged' was not found in type 'Grid'

Comment: Read more carefully. The `SelectionChanged` event is on `ListBox`.